# Comparing processors - high or low bus/core ratio?

Tags: cpu, core

Do I want a high [bus/core ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_multiplier) or a low one?

This is taken from [Intel's site](http://www.intel.com):

```
Bus/Core Ratio  20  22  27  26
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lower ratios are better.  The closer the bus speed matches to the core speed, the faster your computer will operate.